# How to select unique row according to last accessed time

Tags: sql-server, select, date-sorting

I want to get only distinct rows with their respective `AnsId`,

like Qid: 01 have last AnsId: 01

I have following data structure,

```
Qid  Time                  AnsId
01   2011-09-26 12:55:10   01
02   2011-09-26 12:58:32   03
03   2011-09-26 12:59:05   02
01   2011-09-26 01:02:10   01
03   2011-09-26 01:30:10   01
02   2011-09-26 01:59:10   02
```

I have written following query but it returns all the rows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Qid, Time, AnsId
FROM table
ORDER BY Time DESC
```

Then what is missing part in the select query?

Comment: If you want _DISTINCT_ records, you have written the right query: Time is part of resulting record, so you get ALL records...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `row_number()` to find the last answer per `Qid`:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() over (partition by Qid order by Time desc) as rn
        ,       *
        from    YourTable
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   rn = 1
```

The subquery is required because SQL Server doesn't allow `row_number` directly in a `where`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have tested the code, but it is not returning rows in descending order of Time column.. Any help?

Comment: @DarshanJoshi - Just add `order by Time desc` at the end if the query.

Comment: Still getting the rows in ascending order.

Comment: @DarshanJoshi You do know that `12:55:10` is just after lunch and that `01:02:10` is in the middle of the night where a lot of people are sleeping?

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @T table
(
  Qid char(2),
  [Time] datetime,
  AnsId char(2)
)

insert into @T values  
('01',   '2011-09-26 12:55:10',   '01'),
('02',   '2011-09-26 12:58:32',   '03'),
('03',   '2011-09-26 12:59:05',   '02'),
('01',   '2011-09-26 01:02:10',   '01'),
('03',   '2011-09-26 01:30:10',   '01'),
('02',   '2011-09-26 01:59:10',   '02')

select T.Qid,
       T.[Time],
       T.AnsId
from 
    (
      select T.Qid,
             T.[Time],
             T.AnsId,
             row_number() over(partition by T.Qid order by T.[Time] desc) as rn
      from @T as T
    ) as T
where T.rn = 1
order by T.[Time] desc
```

Result:

```
Qid  Time                    AnsId
---- ----------------------- -----
03   2011-09-26 12:59:05.000 02
02   2011-09-26 12:58:32.000 03
01   2011-09-26 12:55:10.000 01
```

Comment: Thanks, the query has returned rows sorted by Time column, but is it possible to get only unique Qid rows?

Comment: @DarshanJoshi - Yes, just remove `, T.AnsId` from the `partition by`. Was not clear to me if you wanted that or not. Now this answer is the same as the one provided by Andomar except for the `order by` clause.